# Bulk Update with Elasticsearch in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I was successfully pushing my docs to my Elasticsearch and already checked it in my Kibana.

My current code is look like this:

```
try:
    res = helpers.bulk(es, my_function(df))
    print("Working")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

and this is "my_function" code:

```
def my_function(df):
    for c, line in enumerate(df):
        yield {
            '_index': 'my_index',
            '_type': '_doc',
            '_id': line.get("_id", None),
            '_source': {
                'field_A': line.get('field', "")
            }
        }
    raise StopIteration
```

Then I wonder what if I run the Python script again in the future to push just some new docs to Elasticsearch. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What are you worrying about exactly?

Comment: I think that if I run this code again, it will push old docs and some new ones, resulting in some duplicate docs that I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on the `_id` you're sending, if it's the same, then there won't be any duplicate, the new version will override the old version.

So not much to worry about, the new documents that don't exist yet, will be indexed and the updates of existing documents will override their older version, provided they are sent with the same `_id`.